# Convert a std::vector of a boost::variant type

Tags: c++, boost, c++98

How might I implement the function below to convert from vector of `Value` to a `Container`? I wish to assert if not all the members of `values` are of the same type, i.e. if the vector contains a mix of strings and ints. This is because the function's return value is either a `std::vector<int>` or a `std::vector<std::string>`.

```
typedef boost::variant<int, std::string> Value;
typedef boost::variant<std::vector<int>, std::vector<std::string> > Container;

Container valuesToContainer(const std::vector<Value>& values) 
{
    return Container();
}
```

Comment: What are you asking. Do you want to know how you can check whether the elements are all of the same type? Or are you asking how to do the conversion? What have you tried so far? Are you aware of `boost::apply_visitor`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  struct converter_visitor : public boost::static_visitor<Container>
  {

         const std::vector<Value> & _cont;
         converter_visitor(const std::vector<Value> &r) : _cont(r) {}

         template<class T>
         Container operator()(const T &) const {
                  std::vector<T> ans;
                  ans.reserve(_cont.size());
                  for (int i=0;i < _cont.size();++i)
                         ans.push_back( boost::get<T>(_cont[i]));
                  return ans;
         }
   };

   Container valuesToContainer(const std::vector<Value> & values) {
         //assuming !values.empty()
         return boost::apply_visitor( converter_visitor(values),values.front());
   }
```

This will throw a `bad_get` if not all the elements of `values` are of the same type.

Answer (score 1):

This could come in handy, maybe:

```
template <typename... T> using VariantVector = std::vector<boost::variant<T...>>;
template <typename... T> using VectorPack    = std::tuple<std::vector<T>...>;

template <typename... T>
    VectorPack<T...> splitVectors(VariantVector<T...> const &values);
```

The difference with the function requested by the OP is that instead of 'erroring' when not all element types agree, it will return a *tuple* of vectors ("VectorPack"), and you can simply select which is the one you want.

Demo program:

```
#include <boost/variant.hpp>
#include <boost/variant/static_visitor.hpp>
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>

using std::get;

template <typename... T> using VariantVector = std::vector<boost::variant<T...>>;
template <typename... T> using VectorPack    = std::tuple<std::vector<T>...>;

namespace detail
{
    template <typename T>
    struct VectorSplitterMixin {
        void operator()(T const& v) { _bucket.push_back(v); }
        std::vector<T> _bucket;
    };

    template <typename... T>
        struct VectorSplitter : boost::static_visitor<>, VectorSplitterMixin<T>...
    {
        typedef VectorPack<T...> product_t;
        product_t product() {
            return product_t { std::move(static_cast<VectorSplitterMixin<T>*>(this)->_bucket)... };
        }
    };
}

template <typename T> struct X;

template <typename... T>
    VectorPack<T...> splitVectors(VariantVector<T...> const &values)
{
    auto splitter = detail::VectorSplitter<T...>();
    for (auto& val : values)
        boost::apply_visitor(splitter, val);
    return splitter.product();
}

int main()
{
    typedef boost::variant<int, std::string> Value;
    typedef boost::variant<std::vector<int>, std::vector<std::string> > Container;

    const std::vector<Value> vec { 42, "hello world", 1, -99, "more" };

    auto vectorPack = splitVectors<int, std::string>(vec);

    for (auto i : get<0>(vectorPack))
        std::cout << "int:" << i << ", ";
    std::cout << "\n";

    for (auto& s : get<1>(vectorPack))
        std::cout << "string:" << s << ", ";
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

Printing:

```
int:42, int:1, int:-99, 
string:hello world, string:more,
```